# Is there a short term for "without a date of expiry"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, abbreviations

Is there a short term for *lack of a date of expiry* when talking about documents? I'm specifically interested in identification document (ID).

Comment: Are you referring to permanent, non-expiring documents, or instead to incomplete / uncompleted forms?

Comment: I'm referring to permanent, non-expiring documents.

Comment: For foods, the term is "stable'. But I don't think that works with documents unless you get people to agree to your use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would simply use the term **non-expiring**. For example, in Washington state, one can obtain a [non-expiring license for child care](http://www.del.wa.gov/laws/development/nonexpiring.aspx).

You may also encounter the phrase **valid *in perpetuity***, e.g. Hawaii Rev. Stat. §481B-13 (about electronic gift cards/certificates):

> …if the gift certificate does not have an expiration date, it shall be valid in perpetuity.

This phrase is generally used in describing the length of effect of a legal document (like a contract or a constitution) or financial instrument rather than an identification, though, so I would consider it a secondary choice.

Answer (score 3):

You could say the identification document has *lifelong validity*.

Answer (score -1):

You could use NONEXP,  meaning non-expiring.

This is a common 'symbol' used with ink stamps, printed labels, and metadata tags.  Though it is not a formal English word/term, it is a very common 'symbol' used on documents for the exact purpose of the OP's question.

Comment: Hi Tamika, and welcome to EL&U. “Nonexp” doesn’t look like an English word. Were you aiming for a contraction of Cameron’s “non-expiring”?

Comment: No, i think Tamika is referring to a common document code, which can take the form of a ink-stamp, a printed label, metadata tag, etc. Despite that this answer is so brief, I think it is good — albeit it could use some context.